# multi select drop down not working angular 2

Tags: angular

**Current Code:** I have used `bootstrap-select.min.js and bootstrap-select.min.css`. And for dropdown styling purpose i have used the class="selectpicker". I have given the below code. With out using the class="selectpicker" dropdown coming without style.

```
<select  class="form-control selectpicker" multiple="multiple"  id="skill"    [(ngModel)]="skills" name="skill"   #skill="ngModel"> <option *ngFor="let skill of skillType.skills" [value]="skill.skill_id"  >{{skill.skill_descr}}</option> </select>
```

**Issue:** problem is when i am using class="selectpicker" dropdown is not showing. when i am checking console it's showing:

```
<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}-->
```

Kindly help me.

Comment: i encourage you to use the NgBootstrap, in order to avoid using any other JS packages, https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples
 
to avoid any unpredictable errors.

Comment: I need multi dropdown, In ngBootstrap i have searched, it's not available. Kindly tell me the solution

Answer (score 0):

I am using Prime NG with Angular 4, see this answer would help you.

```
import {MultiSelectModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
```

Two-way value binding is defined using ngModel and multiselect requires a collection of options where each option should follow the SelectItem interface that defines label-value properties.

**HTML**

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities"></p-multiSelect>
```

**ANGULAR TYPESCRIPT**

```
import {SelectItem} from 'primeng/primeng';

export class MyModel {

    cities: SelectItem[];

    selectedCities: string[];

    constructor() {
        this.cities = [];
        this.cities.push({label:'New York', value:'New York'});
        this.cities.push({label:'Rome', value:'Rome'});
        this.cities.push({label:'London', value:'London'});
        this.cities.push({label:'Istanbul', value:'Istanbul'});
        this.cities.push({label:'Paris', value:'Paris'});
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
this.cities = [];
    this.cities.push({id:'New York', itemName:'New York'});
    this.cities.push({id:'Rome', itemName:'Rome'});
    this.cities.push({id:'London', itemName:'London'});
    this.cities.push({id:'Istanbul', itemName:'Istanbul'});
    this.cities.push({id:'Paris', itemName:'Paris'});
```

Comment: This is literally the copy of the other answer but with much less detail and explanation.